# Can we block or restrict any access token in doorkeeper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, doorkeeper

I am new to using doorkeeper gem.I am using this gem to provide authentication to my rails app for API's. For every request we need access token to process that request. Is there any method or feature by which I can block that particular access token and prevent all the request from that token.
Please suggest and thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that a good approach would be to keep a blacklist with the access tokens that you want to ban, then you have to create a controller action that acts as a middleware before reaching doorkeeper and respond 401 errors in case it is a banned access token